# Stop external usb harddrive from booting

Tags: boot, external-hard-drive

Whenever I boot my machine with an external drive plugged into the usb I get an error:

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device
>   or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot
>   device and press a key

I've reviewed my boot order, but my bios does not list any USB boot options.
How can I stop my motherboard from trying to boot to my external drive?

```
 MB: P4P800SE w/ AMIBIOS 1005 
 ext. HDD: FreeAgent 750gb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I disabled "Legacy USB Support" in the BIOS, the system skipped USB drive detection and booted normally.